# Version conflict occur in Microsoft.Entity.FrameworkCore

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, class-library

I am working on a .net core web application with razor pages. 
My application structure is like :

- DemoCoreApplication with class Libraries "BLL.Data" and "BLL".
  [image]

In BLL.Data, I have made the DB context then I have added the reference of "BLL. Data" project into my main project i.e: **DemoCoreApplication**.

**Refrences in BLL.Data class library:**

[image]

After building the main project (DemoCoreApplication), I got some strange version conflicting errors.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following steps will solve your problem

- Install .Net Core 2.2 SDK (if you don't have)
- Convert all projects in the solution to use .Net Core 2.2
- Rebuild, Start the project